# tinyMCE inline edit and jQuery document ready issue

Tags: jquery, tinymce

I use tinyMCE 4.x/jQuery edition in my (self build) CMS, as inline editor, configured to edit specific areas of html, with different identifiers.

The whole content of each area is directly editable. I am able to make changes and in the end to save them directly to the html file.
However, when using `jquery $(document).ready` function for (ready) jQuery plugins, i face problems. Everything works fine until the editor kicks in.

After making any content changes all links and other content relying on document.ready does not work.
I have created an option to enter and exit edit mode (tinyMCE editor) using  tinymce.execCommand('mceRemoveEditor',false,edId); to switch it off and tinymce.execCommand('mceAddEditor',false,$(this).attr('id')); to switch it on.
(So i can for example navigate trough a content slider and edit content individually)

But once used, even after switching the editor off, each element relying on $(document).ready stops working.

Any recommendation how to solve this problem to make everything in $(document).ready(handler) to work again without to reload the page?
Ideas are greatly appreciated ;-)

Comment: Event-listeners stop working after you edit the html if I understood correctly?

Comment: Well, regardless if i edit html content or not, the Event-listeners stop working after executing tinymce.execCommand (ON and then OFF) Actually, the idea was that i ENABLE/DISABLE the edit mode of the editor, so i can loop trough a slider content and edit seperatelly